# Appending lists with symbol names specified in a list of strings

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

This probably is easy but I cant seem to get

lets say I have `a` `b` and `d`

```
(setq a '(x y))
(setq b '(p q))
(setq d '("a" "b"))
```

how can get a list containing `(x y p q)` with the information I have with `d`

UPDATE;
Ok what I had tried was this

```
(apply 'nconc (mapcar (lambda (x)
               (symbol-value (intern x)))
           d))
```

but I dont really understand what nconc does. if evaluate twice, value changes. thrice emacs
goes without response

Comment: C-h f `nconc` -> nconc alter the last element. Use `concat` instead.

Comment: Why are you evaluating it more than once?

Comment: @Daimrod `concat` returns a string instead of a list.

Comment: nconc is a destructive function: instead of building you a new list without changing the old ones, it modifies the old ones to make the new one.  At least some of the examples below are non-destructive.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman: urf you're right.
@kindahero: Use `(apply 'concatenate 'list (mapcar ...))`

Comment: `(concatenate 'list ...)` just calls `append` and brings in other Common LISP stuff you don't need. It'd be simpler to use `append` or `nconc` depending on what is intended.

Comment: @MichaelHoffman I was writing and evaluating again and again, then saw that behavior. Scott comment it clear.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for that comment. I understand better now.

Comment: *Don't mess with `nconc` or other functions that modify list structure unless you know what you are doing.* If you really need to do modify list structure (instead of creating new lists), you will know it.  Flaunt this guideline at your own peril -- it's very easy to think that things work OK, only to find problems later and often far from whatever really led to the problems.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the suggestion, will keep in mind and thanks a lot for the work you do for emacs community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(apply 'append (mapcar (lambda (name) (symbol-value (intern name))) d))
```

Can you change what `d` to use symbols instead of strings? It would be much simpler to do:

```
(setq d '(a b))
(apply 'append (mapcar 'symbol-value d))
```

If the contents of `a` and `b` are known at the time you set `d`, you could even do this:

```
(setq d `(,@a ,@b))
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I tried. but if My list is huge, emacs cant seem to go anywhere.

Comment: Is this exactly what you tried, or did you try to do something with `nconc`? How big is list `a` and list `b`?

Comment: In fact I tried both. I kinda figured out what I did wrong. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

See [mapcan](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html):

```
(let ((a '(x y))
      (b '(p q))
      (d '("a" "b")))
  (mapcan (lambda (x) (symbol-value (intern x))) d))
```

Answer (score -1):

This should be close:

```
(append (eval (read-from-string (car d))) (eval (read-from-string (cadr d))))
```

If d can be longer, you could map (eval (read-from-string x)) over your list, then apply append to the result; I'll leave that as an exercise :)

Comment: Using `eval` is not really good style and should be avoided like a plague unless you really know that you need it.

Answer (score -1):

My Emacs Lisp foo is not very strong, but maybe you could try the following

```
 (reduce 'append
      (map 'list 
          '(lambda (l) (eval (read l)) ) 
           d ))
```

which should also work for long lists.

Comment: Same as Scott, you don't need eval and shouldn't use it.